# substr: how to exclude special characters like } " _ etc

Tags: sql, oracle, substr

This is the message in the `REMARKS` column of my table

```
{"StatusCode":"0","StatusDescription":"","message":"","transactionid":"404897688","enddate":"04/03/2017","formula":"ACCESS"}_SUBS
{"StatusCode":"0","StatusDescription":"","message":"","transactionid":"404894098","enddate":"04/03/2017","formula":"EVASION"}_SUBN
{"StatusCode":"0","StatusDescription":"","message":"","transactionid":"404889188","enddate":"05/03/2017","formula":"LES CHAINES CANAL+"}_SUBS
{"StatusCode":"0","StatusDescription":"","message":"","transactionid":"404880515","enddate":"06/03/2017","formula":"EVASION+"}_SUBS
```

I am using this in my query

```
substr(remarks, (instr(remarks,'formula') + 10), 18) FORMULA
```

But i am also getting the special characters } " _ because `EVASION+` `LES CHAINES CANAL+` `EVASION` `ACCESS` are not of the same length.

Can someone explain how to exclude those special characters and get only the names displayed under `FORMULA` column.

thanks

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oracle 11g

Comment: Please update your Q with extra information requested, rather than create an every growing chain of comments that people will have to read thru to understand your problem. Good luck.

Comment: This can be done with `substr` and `instr` if performance is a problem and the strings are EXACTLY in the format you provided; but in most cases in problems like this one would use regular expression functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using just the standard `substr` and `instr` functions (no regular expressions):

```
select substr( remarks, instr(remarks, '"formula":"') + 11,
               instr(substr(remarks, instr(remarks, '"formula":"') + 11), '"') - 1 )
from   inputs;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is working perfectly too. FORMULA field now has the exact data i need :)

Answer (score 1):

If the remarks column is just a string, you might try:

```
with x as (
select '{"StatusCode":"0","StatusDescription":"","message":"","transactionid":"404897688","enddate":"04/03/2017","formula":"ACCESS"}_SUBS' as remarks
from dual
)
select
regexp_substr(remarks, '"formula":"(.*?)"',1,1,'i',1)
from x;
```

Output:

```
ACCESS
```

Comment: is it possible to just change this one line of query to get that output? because i have other substr lines in the query too. I was only having doubt with the lines i posted above

Comment: The solution works on the strings exactly as given, but the greedy match `(.*)` is dangerous; if there are other double-quotes further in the string, everything will be matched up to the last double-quote. "Reluctant" match, `(.*?)`, should be used in problems like this.

Comment: @SaiAvinash yes, the regexp_substr line is the one you want, the rest is just to setup some test data to operate on.

Comment: @mathguy I think it depends on what you want.  If the data has a double quote, that may be valid.  So "formula"="string with " quote" you may very well want to return: 'string with " quote' instead of just 'string with'.

Comment: @tbone - in this type of data, a double-quote shouldn't be part of regular text (certainly not unescaped). Rather, what I meant was - what if the `formula` field is not the last one in the list? What if it is somewhere in the middle?

Comment: @mathguy Ok, I see what you're saying, good point.  I'll update my answer

Comment: @tbone thank you very much. Just using the regexp line worked perfectly.